# Pytube error: urllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 404: Not Found

Tags: python, pytube

```
from pytube import YouTube

url = 'https://youtu.be/7hvcJK5-OLI'
my_video = YouTube(url)

print("=================== Video Title ====================")
print(my_video.title)                                             # This prints the title of the youtube video

print("=================== Thumbnail Image ====================")
print(my_video.thumbnail_url)                                     # This prints the thumbnail link in terminal

print("=================== Download Video ====================")

choise = input("Do you want to download mp3 or mp4: ")

if choise.lower() == 'mp4':
    my_video = my_video.streams.get_highest_resolution()          # We set the resolusion of the video

elif choise.lower() == 'mp3':
    my_video = my_video.streams.get_audio_only()                  # To get only audio we set this

else:
    print("Invalid option! ")
    exit()

my_video.download()
```

This is my code. I am trying to make simple youtube downloader for project but it keep throwing HTTP Error: 404, although even my url is correct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to update `pytube` to latest version `10.8.5`

Just run `pip install --upgrade pytube`